# Query in Oracle is not executing if records are more than 100k

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using database oracle 11g.
My application runs query like following in some specific scenario

```
Select distinct demo.table1.id, demo.table2.status 
FROM demo.table1, demo.table2
WHERE demo.table1.id=demo.table2.id
AND ((demo.table2.userID = '1') or (demo.table2.userID='2'))
```

It gives me correct output if number of records are about 20-25K.
But query does not return anything and application hangs if number of records are more than 50K.

However, if I remove 'AND' condition; query gives me desired output(i.e. 50K records)

I ran same scenario for MSSQL server 2005, all above specified scenarios worked well. Application didn't hang even for 100K records.

I don't know what is going wrong here. Is it my query or do I need to make some configuration changes in oracle?

Please help me here as I am new to oracle database.

Comment: If you remove AND condition you will get more records. AND conditions always reduce amounts of records. Are you sure?

Comment: If userid is a `number` column you should also use numbers to compare it. `'1'` is a string, `1` is a number. Never compare apples (strings) to oranges (numbers)

Comment: @knagaev: I was too surprised by seeing this. I have done this lot of times and gives same result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes. userID is string.

Comment: @user1597376 is userID indexed? also how many rows are in table2 and how many rows of those match userID '1' or '2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition... You may consider getting rid of distinct. It slows down the performance greatly. I believe this is why your query hangs. Then I'd replace OR with UNION/UNION ALL - depends... Here's some general example on how to avoid distinct:

```
-- DISTINCT --
SELECT DISTINCT d.deptno, dname FROM scott.dept D, scott.emp E 
 WHERE D.deptno = E.deptno
/  

-- Same as Distinct but may be faster --
SELECT deptno, dname FROM scott.dept D 
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'X' FROM scott.emp E WHERE E.deptno = D.deptno)
/
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have indexes on any fields you want to join on and any fields you use in your where criteria.  Looks like at minimum, Table1.id, Table2.Id and Table2.userID.

Then I'd recommend changing your query to the following using an `INNER JOIN` and an `IN` clause:

```
Select DISTINCT t.id, t2.status 
FROM demo.table1 t
   INNER JOIN demo.table2 t2 on t.id=t2.id
WHERE demo.table2.userID IN (1,2)
```

--EDIT

I don't understand why your userId field is a string - this should probably be refactored as an identity/auto increment.  However, you'd need to adjust the WHERE clause above to be IN ('1','2') to work.

Good luck.